# how to fetch reviews and comments posted for app inside chrome web store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

here is the sample header field.

Request URL:https://chrome.google.com/reviews/components

Request payload:

```
req={
"appId": 94,
"version": "121024",
"reqId": "1363687747823-0.8877600133419037",
"hl": "en",
"specs": [
    {
        "type": "CommentThread",
        "url": "http%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fpermalink%3Fid%3Danekiipncldokmaojfkbfecgfjjjekoc",
        "groups": "chrome_webstore",
        "sortby": "date",
        "startindex": "0",
        "numresults": "25",
        "id": "1616"
    }
],
"internedKeys": [],
"internedValues": []
}
```

response is json file which contain review.

how to make automated system which get appID and featch review related to that app.